# Make list elements on left and top stick to position in react-native android

Tags: android, react-native, sticky

This is the code in render

```
<ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
    <View style={styles.epgRow}>
        /*this view sticks on left properly*/
        <ListView
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={this.renderLogo}
            style={styles.listView}
            />
        <ScrollView horizontal={true} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} style={{flex:4}}>
            <View style={styles.epgCol}>
                <ScrollView vertical={false} style={{flex:4}}>
                    <Text>"ok"</Text>
                    /*This does not stick on top*/
                </ScrollView>
                <ListView
                    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                    renderRow={this.renderEpgCol}
                    style={styles.listView}
                    />
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
    </View>
</ScrollView>
```

This is the stylessheet

```
epgRow: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
    },
    epgRowTime: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
    },
    epgRowContainer: {
        borderWidth: 0.5,
        width : 300,
        height: 81
    },
    showName: {
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: 'center',
        borderRightWidth: 10,
    },
    thumbnail: {
        width: 80,
        height: 80,
        backgroundColor: '#bdbdbd',
    },
    listView: {
        flex:1
    }
```

Left list view sticks on left properly but the top text "ok" doesn't stick on top. How do I make the test "ok" stick on top? position:fixed is not allowed in react-native. And the sticky sections example work only in iOS not in Android.

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to place the section you want to stick on top outside of the ScrollView.

```
<ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
    <View style={styles.epgRow}>
        /*this view sticks on left properly*/
        <ListView
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={this.renderLogo}
            style={styles.listView}
            />
        <ScrollView vertical={false} style={{flex:4}}>
            <Text>"ok"</Text>
            /*This does not stick on top*/
        </ScrollView>
        <ScrollView horizontal={true} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} style={[styles.epgCol, {flex:4}]}>
                <ListView
                    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                    renderRow={this.renderEpgCol}
                    style={styles.listView}
                    />
        </ScrollView>
    </View>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: vertical={false} does not work inside a vertical scrollview.